# Can ffmpeg process rtmp stream from FMS at all?

Tags: ffmpeg, flash-media-server, rtmp

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp:/vid2/recordings -acodec copy -vcodec copy -y captured.flv
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/vid2/recordings -acodec copy -vcodec copy -y captured.flv
```

The above command only give me this error:

```
rtmp://localhost/vid2/recordings: no such file or directory
```

Isn't **ffmpeg** supposed to be able to handle **rtmp** streams?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the Xuggler version of ffmpeg? Here's a tutorial explaining how to obtain and encode rtmp streams with the Xuggler ffmpeg.

http://wiki.xuggle.com/Live_Encoding_Tutorial

Answer (score 2):

No need to use Xuggler's build. Version .6 of ffmpeg does support rtmp. However, make sure you compile with

```
--enable-librtmp
```

Answer (score 0):

appears it can (analyzeduration to get rid of an initial delay)

```
$ ffplay -analyzeduration 0 -i "rtmp://localhost/live/stream_name live=1"
```

See http://betterlogic.com/roger/2012/08/ffmpeg-receiving-rtmp-stream-from-flash-media-server/ for some instructions on how to stream to it, as well.

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` can catch the stream of `rtmp`. Try it with entering port like `1935`

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/newStream
```

But before doing that check if `newStream` exist. If not, open new `cmd` and enter `ffmpeg/bin` folder

```
ffmpeg -i sample.avi -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/newStream
```

Then try to run first code.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with FFMPEG.

I publish video from FFMPEG on FMS correctly and I can see that on the FMS video player.

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/videos/sample.mp4 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/sample
```

Now I would like to create live stream.

For this case I use this code in the FFMPEG on linux:

```
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/sample -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv     rtmp://localhost/livepkgr/sample_streamd?adbe-live-event=sample_event
```

By use this syntax I get same error:

```
Closing connection: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
rtmp://localhost:1935/live/sample: Operation not permitt
```